# I keep receiving the script say "window.location.reload()" when use httpwebrequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

```
<!--@R--><script>
var k ='c991130d';
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime() + (3600*24*365*5*1000));
document.cookie = "p7c=" + k +";  
expires=" + d.toGMTString();
setTimeout(function(){
window.location.reload(); },2000);
</script>
please wait....
```

when I use my code to get a web page I keep getting these, but I can use XMLhttp with VB to get the whole page, it's my code below:

```
public static string GetPage(string Url)
{
HttpWebRequest WebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(Url);
WebRequest.Timeout = 5000;
WebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
WebRequest.Headers.Set("Pragma", "no-cache");

try
{
   using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)WebRequest.GetResponse())
   {
      using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
      {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8")))
           { return sr.ReadToEnd(); }
      }
   }
}
catch (Exception ex){ return "%ERROR%" + ex.Message; }
}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on the specific question, but it might be related to post back, try checking `if(isPostBack)` in your code behind. Another thought, if you are trying to get that page and the javaScript is executing wouldn't that loop over and over again every 2 seconds?